# Scroll to Top does not work after hiding elements (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Currently I have a function for my menu that scrolls to different divs on the page, as a form of navigation. Currently I'm using the following method.

Scroll to Portfolio

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#portfolio').offset().top }, 600);
```

Since I'm building the entire page dynamically, when someone clicks on a link, I am using .hide() to hide main page elements, and generating additional content.

```
function hideElements() {

$("#something").hide();

}
```

While on the content page, if they want to go back to portfolio, they click on the portfolio link again. I'm using the following method to "scroll" them to the re-shown element.

```
$("#nav").click(){
    unhideMainElements();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#portfolio').offset().top }, 1200);
    $("#container").fadeIn(300);
}
```

**The problem is, the fade will work, but it won't scroll to the element. I'd figure it has to do with .hide() the element and .show() the element, but I don't know why. I appreciate any insight. Thanks!**

Comment: Does it scroll to a different element, or does it not scroll at all?

Comment: It scrolls to any element that wasn't hidden using .hide(). If it used .hide() or .show(), it doesn't scroll to it.

Comment: jQuery can't find the position of a hidden element. [See the docs.](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) Apparently your elements aren't being `.show`n before you try to find their position.

Comment: console.log($('#portfolio').offset().top) shows that it's giving a 0, meaning it doesn't find the right offset. This could be the source of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `hide()` and `show()`, why don't you try `.animate({'opacity':0})` to hide and then `.animate({'opacity':1})` to show.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the [`visibility`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) proprety instead of `display` :

```
$('#something').css({'visibility':'hidden'}); //or visible
```

The element should keep his native dimensions without been showed.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

The two functions of animation and `fadeIn` were put into the `.show()` callback in  `unhideMainElements();`. That way, the animation will only fire when all the `.show()` completes.

I guess it was a timing thing.

Thanks for your help.